# I want to check all table rows in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ember.js

I want to check all table rows and if all values are same alert('ok) in Ember.js
Here is my Code.

```
actions:{
  checkValue: function(){
    var r = this.$('.cellValue').text();
    if(r == '|'){
      console.log('ok');
    }else{
      console.log('bad');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you want ? what is wrong ?

Comment: I have a table and when you click on the data it's changes his value : And if all cell value become same alert('smth) but in my code it's not working

Comment: if nothing is showing then you are not calling checkvalue function .

Comment: How can i call it, it's working only when i click

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  The best questions here are called "MCVE" meaning "Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Examples".  Read about how to ask here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  Your question is not complete, you should include your template and more.  Is your code above in a controller, route, component?

Comment: Thank you. It is above in component

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you're going about this problem in a non-Ember way.  Why don't you try something like this:

Component.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  rows: [
    {name: 'bob', value: "24"},
    {name: 'peter', value: "32"}
  ],

  checkValue: Ember.observer('rows.@each.value', function () {
    const unique = Ember.get(this, 'rows').uniqBy('value')
    if (unique.length === 1) alert('matching')
  })

});
```

Template.hbs

```
<table>
  {{#each rows as |row|}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{row.name}}</td><td><input value={{row.value}} onblur={{action (mut row.value) value='target.value'}}></td>
  </tr>
  {{/each}}
</table>
```

There is a Twiddle [here](https://ember-twiddle.com/53096495c449783ef196ad51c7632d00?openFiles=templates.components.my-component.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs)

Comment: Thank you very much, you can see my answer on the top and if you can help me, please.